# extjs cannot process conditional statement

Tags: extjs, panel, toolbar

I have a extjs `tabpanel` and a `toolbar` defined like this.

```
tbar : {
{
xtype:'box',
tpl:[
'<table><tr><td>',
'<b>Total Prelim Shares:</b> ',
'</td><tpl if="totalPrelimShares < 0" ><td width="30" style = "color:red">',
'{totalPrelimShares}',
'</td></tpl><td width="10">',
'<span class="xtb-sep"></span>',
'</td><td>',
'<b>Total Prelim Gross Amount:</b>',
'</td><td width="70">',
'{totalPrelimGrossAmount}',
'</td><td>',
'<b>Total Prelim Net Amount:</b>',
'</td><td width="70">',
'{totalPrelimNetAmount}',
'</td></tr><table>'             

],
ref:'../ipTotalBar',
data:{totalPrelimShares :'0'}
}
}
```

I call it like this:

```
var obj = {totalPrelimShares :  -10,totalPrelimNetAmount:20,totalPrelimGrossAmount : 30 };
this.ipTotalBar.update(obj);
```

No errors, but the `{totalPrelimShares}` does not show up. When I remove the `tpl if="totalPrelimShares < 0" >`, it works fine.

Comment: are you using & gt; or & lt, also make sure you define your template as  Ext.XTemplate. I think the default may be Ext.Template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you're experiencing may be because the `XTemplate` does not know what `totalPrelimShares` is. In the examples in the [`XTemplate` documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.XTemplate.html), whenever using a variable passed into the template configuration (like `totalPrelimShares`, in your case), it is always referred to using `this.*`. For example:

```
<tpl if="this.totalPrelimShares < 0">
```

If that doesn't work, you can also try using the inline operators `{[ ... ]}` as defined in the documentation:

```
<tpl if="{[totalPrelimShares]} < 0">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tpl if="totalPrelimShares < 0" >
```

must be

```
<tpl if="totalPrelimShares &lt; 0" >
```

`<`, `>` and `"` must be written as entities `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&quot;` respectively if used within the conditional. The documentation is wrong on this one.